# Dart: Logic for/if

Tags: dart

I have a logic problem, this is my code:

```
  bool teste = true;

  for (int j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    verifyAllProd(items[j].ref).then(
      (quanti) {
        if (double.parse(quanti) <= 0) {
          teste = false;
          _dialogBuilder(context, items[j].name);
        }
        if (double.parse(quanti) <
                items[j].quantity &&
            double.parse(quanti) != 0) {
          teste = false;
          _dialogBuilder2(
              context, items[j].name, quanti);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  if (teste) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            const ListPaymentTrans(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

That I wanted the last "if" to happen when:
The **"for"** was running but it didn't enter any **"if"**, if they enter one then it shows the message and no longer opens another window, ie the last if.

But this is not happening, when I run the code it starts to go through the **"for"** and at the same time opens the **"if"**, can anyone help?

Comment: Yeah. "Dart: Logic for/if".  The logic behind statements in Dart is not very different from other languages. It turns out that you want to get an answer, but don't even know how to ask the right question? In your opinion, this is the right question - "Dart: Logic for/if".

Comment: You have already written a test, but you still do not understand exactly the logic of these statements `if/for`?

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: my problem is that the last "if" is being executed without knowing if the "teste" value was changed to false

Comment: Write a test and if you don't succeed, write about it here and they will definitely help you. Because right now it's hard to understand what you want to get and why you can't get it. First you wrote that the problem is in Flutter, then you kindly agreed that the problem is in Dart. And all this because you don't understand the logic of `if/for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you have an async function `verifyAllProd` here. The code inside `then` will run async, so the last "if" will run first of all.

Eg: "end" will go first, then all the "verify" will go after.

```dart
Future<String> verify(String text) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));
  return 'verified_$text';
}

void main() {
  const count = 5;
  for(int i = 0; i < count;i++){
    verify('count$i').then((verifiedText) {
      print(verifiedText);
    });
  }
  print('end.');
}
// end.
// verified_count0
// verified_count1
// verified_count2
// verified_count3
// verified_count4
```

[image]

You may want to wait all the async function done first, try to use async/await like this

[image]

Comment: Oh.  How long has it been since `async` and `await` support was added to Dart? I don't understand why use the `then` method (instead of the new `async` and `await`features) without having an idea of how inconvenient it is (in many cases) and then asking the question - "Well, why does everything work so wrong?" . P.S. These features were added in Dart 1.9.

Comment: Tuan ty for help it's already working as I wanted

Comment: @mezoni I don't remember but I rarely use "then", it's really inconvenient in most cases.